# Allowing OpenID only login to Drupal

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

We are looking to allow logins in our university Drupal instance via OpenID for non-university account holders. We currently use the [CAS module](http://drupal.org/project/cas) to authenticate university account holders.

We want to use OpenID instead of Drupal core accounts because we don't want to store passwords, passwords are sent in the clear, no HTTPS, etc. We'd like to offload authentication to services like Facebook, Google and Twitter by using OpenID and the [OpenID Selector module](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector). The problem is, with the Drupal account creation setting set to "Administrators only", OpenID throws the error "Only site administrators can create new user accounts." when you try to log in with OpenID. The CAS module works correctly to set up new users accounts with this same setting.

I need a way to bypass this setting when authenticating via OpenID. Is there a module that handles this, or can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.